# Proof for the convergence of the trapezoid rule for ODES

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-explanation

I was following the Wikipedia footnotes for a proof that the trapezoid rule converges and I arrived at the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The author first shows that the local truncation error is $O(h^3)$ in the context as $h\to \infty$. Then he claims that we can bound the $O(h^3)$ term by $ch^3$. So far, so good. However, he then goes on to say that we are interested in the case $h\rightarrow0$ and uses the same bounds. I do not think that this is OK because by the same argument $1+h$ is $O(h^2)$  meaning $1+h<dh^2$, and so, taking the limit as $h\rightarrow 0 $ gives $1<0$. Could someone check if I am misunderstanding what is written?

Comment: No, the equivalent is that $(1+h)-e^h=O(h^2)$.

Comment: Could you clarify how the author got to $O(h^2)$?

Comment: This comes from the sum over $n$ steps, $nh^3=t_nh^2$. Or more precisely here the sum over a geometric series $$(1+(1+ch)+(1+ch)^2+...+(1+ch)^{n-1})h^3=\frac{(1+ch)^n-1}{(1+ch)-1}h^3=\frac1c((1+ch)^n-1)h^2\approx\frac1c(e^{ct_n}-1)h^2.$$

Comment: Apologies. I meant to ask, on the first page, how did he get to $O(h^3)$?

Comment: By inserting appropriate Taylor expansions. You can get this more symmetrically and systematically by using $t_*=t_n+h/2=t_{n+1}-h/2$ as basis point for the expansions. You could equally well use linear interpolation $y'(x)=y'(x_0)+y'[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+y'[x_0,x_1,x](x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ and insert this into the fundamental theorem.